# 2001 ford e250 no start but has spark

Tags: ford, fuel-system, cranks-wont-run, e250

2001 Ford E250 not properly long term stored. I can get it to crank/turn over but it will not run at all. It has 200,000 miles on it but has never had this problem before. I shoot a bit of starting fluid and it'll run for a split second. So I know its got fire. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: How long was it stored?

Comment: I would start with making sure that the grounds and the battery terminals are clean and tight. I would look for signs of nesting and then signs of damage to wiring. Signs of puddling or staining on/near connectors etc. Ruling out environmental issues first.

Answer (score 1):

You should start with:

1) have you got sufficient fuel? How much in the tank?

2) is it fresh - old / degraded fuel may not ignite.

3) is it getting to the cylinders? Fuel filter? Carbs blocked? Spark plugs getting wet?

You may need to clean the old fuel out and get fresh fuel all through the system.

Comment: Because the engine fires (briefly) when starting fluid is added, you can conclude that the starting and ignition systems are operating correctly. Thus, the engine isn't running because fuel is not getting into the cylinders. Address each of the items @Solar Mike has mentioned in his Answer above.